# How to hit a HttpPost-action with a parameter?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, frombodyattribute

I have an API with a

```
[HttpPost("InsertSomething")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertSomething(Guid id, [FromBody] MyModel model)
{
   try
   {
      ...
      Guid somethingId = await _myService.Insert(id, enz..)
```

and when I wanna calling this Action

```
HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync("/MyContr/InsertSomething", content);
```

then i will come in the Action of the API.

... and when you add something like this

```
HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync($"/MyContr/InsertSomething?id=BlaBlaBla", content);
```

then we did not comein the Action of the API.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please include specific error or response you see?

Comment: I didn't see an error. But nothing will saved and when you set a break point, the cursor will never arrive in the API. That's just my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your endpoint like this:

```
 [HttpPost("InsertSomething")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> InsertSomething([FromQuery]Guid id, [FromBody] MyModel model)
```

also, make sure that you are passing correct guid.